# No change can be responsible for an essence ceasing to exist?

Tags: essence, change

Essences - assuming there are no bare essences - of things that exist, exist forever.

I think so, and I even have my own most argument for it below. Which philosophers agree or disagree? It may have some "far out" entailments.

1. A changing thing must cross the boundary of its two states (if not, change would have two different movements, when it meets the boundary and when it has crossed it, which is impossible, because movements have extent, and [two things with extent cannot belong to one boundary](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boundary/#ReaThe)).
2. If the essence ceases to exist with the change, then the essence does not cross that boundary.
3. And any thing always has its essence (even when it crosses a boundary)
4. Therefore, nothing changes - becomes something else - so that its essence ceases to exist.

There is no change? There are no boundaries? They are not crossed? There are no states? Movements have no extent?

---

Then either perception has no essence, or something inside perception exists eternally. Can it have no essence, not even the absence of any determinate essence?

Comment: I may have rushed it. I needs a "hobby"

Comment: On standard conceptions, [essences](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/essential-accidental/) are collections of core properties that belong to substances, and it is ambiguous what "cease to exist" means as applied to them, as opposed to substances. As either ideal aspects or abstractions they do "exist eternally" in the thin sense of "exist" that applies to those things. In the more tangible sense of "exist" they cease to exist along with their substance, so the question really is if the substance can cease to exist.

Comment: right so you're answer is "no". unless abstract. in what sense do abstract entities exist forever? @Conifold I dunno why you linked to an article that doesn't support anything you say in any sense. annoying

Comment: so does anyone disagree @Conifold ?

Comment: I feel like shit about myself whenever you leave a comment on my questions, and not because I made a mistake in them @Conifold is it deliberate?

Comment: Perhaps if you did not create a new sock puppet every week it would be easier to tell which questions are yours, but as it is...

Comment: I'm not gonna get an answer, so I don't suppose it matters

Comment: The further conclusions that there is no change doesn't follow even if the argument holds since assuming hylomorphism it is the matter not the form (essence) that undergoes change. What ceases to exist is the compound of matter and form (e.g. a bronze statue of Perseus). So the relevance/point of the argument is unclear. Aristotle's theory does face difficulties in dealing with certain kinds of substantial change where the matter and form of a substance don't come apart in an unproblematic way, see [Ackrill's problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-psychology/suppl1.html)

Comment: [Essences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essence) do not change.

Comment: yeah sorry it was a dumb thing to post